# How to provoke button click on web page from integration test

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, automated-tests

Our backend is thoroughly tested with unit tests. Now we need to pull all the pieces together with integration tests. I see lots of examples for how to "get" a page, but none for how to execute functionality on the page.
I have a standard HTML "Scan" page with a download button.
Looks like this:

```
        <li><img src="~/img/download.png" style="height: 1.5em; width: inherit; margin-right: 8px" /><a id="download-btn" href="#">Download</a></li>
```

Click the button and it downloads a PDF. Works fine.
The js starts like this:

```
$('#download-btn').click(function () { 
var qrKey = 'c40rj8f'; // Replace with your actual QRKey value

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Scans/Download',
    method: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    data: { QRKey: qrKey },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer', // Important for handling binary data
    success: function (response) {
    ....
```

Now I need to test that from my Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting integration test.

Between stackoverflow, chatgpt and copilot, this is the closest I've been able to come up with, but it returns 400.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ScanDownloadTest()
    {
        // get page content
        var page = await httpClient.GetAsync("Scan");
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, page.StatusCode);
        string resultContent = page.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        // load the page into an HtmlDocument 
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(resultContent);
        var downloadBtn = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("download-btn");
        // execute downloadBtn button click 
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Scan");
        var content = new StringContent($"{{\"id\":1,\"method\":\"Runtime.evaluate\",\"params\":{{\"expression\":\"document.getElementById('{downloadBtn.Id}').click();\",\"returnByValue\":true}}}}");
        request.Content = content;
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); // returns 400 (Bad Request)
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content.Headers.ContentType);
        Assert.AreEqual("application/octet-stream", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Are you looking to test an actual UI?  Or just test a manual HTTP request/response?  The title implies the former, but the code shown implies the latter.  (Well, the second half of it does.  The first half of it makes a request and asserts a successful response, then performs a few superfluous operations that do nothing.)  Regarding the 400 response... Do you control the server to which you're making that request?  What request is it expecting?  We don't know what's a "good" or "bad" request for any arbitrary URL anywhere on the internet.

Comment: @David It is expecting the user to click the button.  "Post" doesn't seem right, but that's what the example had.

Comment: If your goal is to actually *click* a UI element then you'd need something which interfaces with that UI.  For web UIs you might look into using something like Selenium.  It includes a "headless" option so no visible browser is opened, but internally the application would be using browser functionality (a rendering engine, a JavaScript engine, etc.) to interact with the target page.  The code shown simply isn't doing this at all.  It requests a page, finds an element on that page (`download-btn`), then abandons that entirely and sends a new request to the server.

Comment: I think you are correct that it goes to all that work to find the ID of the button, which is silly since it finds it **by id**.

Comment: I assume from your comment that this great testing framework can only test GETs and POSTs. Is there a way to write the page so that it invokes the button click through routing? Say `/Scan/Download`

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by that.  GETs and POSTs are types of HTTP requests.  Routing is (part of) how the server-side code determines how to respond to those requests.  These are not different kinds of the same thing at all.  If you're trying to test the server's response to specific requests, you can use your current approach and make HTTP requests to the server, checking the response accordingly.  If you're trying to test the actual UI to make sure it's performing expected actions and updating itself in expected ways, you'd use a UI automation tool (e.g. Selenium).

Comment: I'm trying to create an integration test that causes the web page to talk with the backend and retrieve data from the database. I am not trying to unit test the UI. OTOH, I do want it to go through the javascript and not call the controller directly. I'd rather, if possible, stay within VS and Test Explorer rather than use a completely separate tool.

Comment: *"causes the web page to [...] not trying to unit test the UI [...] I do want it to go through the javascript"* - You seem to be struggling to separate these concepts and clearly define what you're actually trying to test.  The UI includes the buttons and other elements and the client-side code responding to clicks.  The server-side endpoints are HTTP operations which accept a request and return a response.  Are you **only** trying to test the requests/responses, or are you **also** trying to test that the UI interactions **performs** those requests?

Comment: In my experience with Selenium, albeit several years ago, it was great for testing that the website acted and responded correctly but was cumbersome for integration testing.

Comment: I'm not clear on what's not clear. An integration test tests from top to bottom. I don't want to start in the middle by calling the controller. I want to provoke the button click event.  Interestingly, and I didn't know you could do this, we don't have any controllers that return pages. All the routing is handled in the pages themselves, like `@page "/Scan"`.  Perhaps a tag in the page, like `/Scan#download` and then #download would respond by invoking the onClick event?

Comment: *"I want to provoke the button click event."* - That's the UI.  Interacting with the UI of a web application would involve browser-like functionality.  So in that case you're looking for either Selenium or something like it.  Any "headless browser" tool which internally includes a rendering engine, JavaScript engine, etc.  It would make a request to the target URL, internally render the page and allow you to interact with the DOM in code (find and click a specific element), etc.  It doesn't *need* to be Selenium specifically, that's just a popular example to illustrate the overall concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a much more difficult question to answer than it should be.
I knew for certain that it could be done because I've done it many times in the past. Of course that was with WebBrowser, which of course was based on IE, which of course isn't supported, so of course isn't available in Core.
Surely MS has some sort of replacement. Right? No. Not so much.
There is, of course Selenium, and I did get that working from my NUnit tests. But you have to start your website independently, which I didn't get working.
And there were numerous posts touting the `WebApplicationFactory<T>` as all you'll ever need for your End-to-End testing. But after hours of following tutorials, you find that it only calls your controllers. Not quite E2E.

In the end, I used Martin Costello's [dotnet-minimal-api-integration-testing](https://github.com/martincostello/dotnet-minimal-api-integration-testing/tree/main) project as a base. This uses  `WebApplicationFactory<T>` combined with [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/).

Ideally, this would be converted into a NuGet plugin, but for now, there's about 4 hours work to convert it into a generically usable form and excise xunit.

My code to test "login button works and takes you to the scan page," now looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void LoginSuccessTestRunner() {
        Run(LoginSuccessTest);
    }

    public async Task LoginSuccessTest(IPage page) {
        // Arrange
        Task scan = page.WaitForURLAsync(Fixture.ServerAddress + "Scan", WaitOptions);
        await page.GotoAsync(Fixture.ServerAddress + "Login");
        await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LoadState.Load);
        // Act
        await page.TypeAsync("id=username", "admin");
        await page.TypeAsync("id=password", "password");
        await page.ClickAsync("id=submit");
        await scan; // Wait for the Scan page to finish loading

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Scan - Frontend", await page.TitleAsync());
    }
```